# Is it possible to keep wolves from following you?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is it possible in Minecraft to stop tamed wolves from following you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you right-click a tamed wolf, it will sit. This prevents it from following you.

Further details can be found in the Minecraft Wiki article on Wolves, specifically on the [movement](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wolf#Movement) section.

Answer (score 1):

right click the wolf, it will command it to sit and stay at the position. It won't move from that spot.. no matter what (even if you light it on fire for example)

Comment: Not entirely true. They will move if you are attacked.

Answer (score -1):

Take a bone and at the bottom it will say stop following me if you are by your dog then it will say follow me if you want them to

Comment: please note the [minecraft java edition] tag. this answer is for bedrock, **not** java. this answer also isnt worded too well and could be hard to understand.